# Undefined method for method in another class

Tags: ruby

Sorry for the potentially stupid question, I'm quite new to Ruby, and object orientation all together, however, I get
    dby.rb:30:in `<class:DBYConfig>': undefined method`parse' for DBY::DBYConfig:Class     (NoMethodError)
    from dby.rb:8:in `<module:DBY>'
    from dby.rb:6:in`'
Here is the code:

https://gist.github.com/zackp30/6374d13ee1f88948c833

Comment: put the whole **gist** code in your post itself.

Comment: Sorry, was having issues with the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#parse` is an instance method of the class `DBYConfig`, that's why you got error. Change `DBY::DBYConfig.parse` to `DBY::DBYConfig.new.parse`. Same explanation go to the method `#init_conf`, as with `#parse` . Thus change `DBY::DBYConfig.init_conf`, to `DBY::DBYConfig.new.init_conf`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! (And sorry to waste your time with this.)

Comment: @user3289461 np..I am sitting here, really to waste my time :) :)